Passing an unlocked LUKS partition context from GRUB to Linux?
Question
In GRUB one can use the cryptomount command to mount a LUKS partition.
Is there a way to pass this decrypted partition to linux such that it appears as a device mapper (/dev/mapper/xxx) entry without having to run cryptsetup luksOpen?
If it's not possible with GRUB, are there other bootloaders that support this?
Notes
Some distributions support cryptdevice/cryptkey parameters, however this doesn't appear to be a standard linux kernel parameter (and isn't supported by the distribution I use).
There is also the dm-mod.create kernel parameter but it appears that it only supports cleartext passphrase (viewable from /proc/cmdline) or use a linux keyring entry.
Both of these methods would need to decrypt the partition again in order for linux to mount it though, right? Or else why would they need the key?


Both of these methods would need to decrypt the partition again in order for linux to mount it though, right? Or else why would they need the key?

The "unlocked context" that you're talking about is the decryption key.
Or in other words, the partition doesn't get 'decrypted' in the way of flipping a switch – it's not some kind of external hardware or firmware session that could be carried over through the boot process "if only GRUB didn't re-lock it" (like might be the case with smart cards, or OPAL self-encrypting HDDs).
Rather, the only thing that unlocking the LUKS device does is unseal the volume's 'master' key from a LUKS keyslot, for use in continuous decryption which happens as part of every read or write operation. The /dev/mapper device acts as a filter which relies on having the master key to decrypt data on the fly.
So the only way for GRUB to pass the unlocked state to the OS is to have it stash the LUKS 'master' key somewhere that Linux could then find it and set up a /dev/mapper dm-crypt device using that key. As far as I can see, GRUB has no support for anything like that in its cryptodisk module.
